# Monitoring signals on a bus with LEDs

Tags: digital-logic, bus, logic-level, monitor

I'm looking for a way to visually monitor logic signals on a bus with use of LEDs of different colours. The conditions are:

1. I want to be able to visually distinguish the following states:
   a) **Logical 1** (high, +5V) = the **red LED** lights up;
   b) **Logical 0** (low, 0V) = the **green LED** lights up;
   c) **Disconnected** (floating, high impedance) = **either both LEDs shine or none**.
2. The monitor circuit **cannot disturb the bus** in any way, that is, it doesn't introduce high or low voltage which could be interpreted as 0 or 1 by the circuit which reads from the bus.

**My previous attempt** was with two LEDs in series (red and green) between +5V and ground, with two resistors in series with each diode, and the probing input being the connection point between these two LEDs. And it *kinda* worked: When the middle point was shorted to ground by the logic circuit's output, there was a current from +5V through the upper diode and through the circuit into ground, making the upper LED light up, and the lower one was off because it had 0V on both terminals. When the middle point was asserting high, the upper diode was off (+5V on both terminals) and the current from the circuit went through the lower diode and its resistor to ground. When the circuit's output switched to high impedance (that is, reading from the bus), both LEDs were lighting up, because there was a slight current from +5V to ground through both diodes and their resistors.

But the problem with this approach was that when the circuit was reading from the bus, the LED monitor was influencing the signals on the bus, making the circuit read 1s from all lines. I suppose it's because the voltage at the middle point between the LEDs was interpreted as logical 1 since it was not 0V :P (But I guess 0V wouldn't be good either, because then it could be interpreted as 0, overriding the actual data on the bus.)

Do you know of any solution of these problems? Is there any way to monitor the logical signals (and high impedance) on the bus without disturbing the signals on it?

INB4: How fast those signals change shouldn't be your concern. They change slow enough for me to observe, because I operate them in slow-motion. It is a test project, not some actual super-fast bus.

**Edit:** I'm not looking for a logic probe circuit – that would only probe one line. I rather want to monitor all of them at once, so the less elements required the better.

**Edit 2:** To all nitpicky smart-asses out there: by **non-disturbing** I don't mean breaking the Heisenberg's uncertainty principle, just reading what's on the bus without writing any signals on it at the same time which would disturb whatever signals are already there. (Not to mention that we're not talking about quantum-level measurements here, so Heisenberg's uncertainty doesn't even apply anyway ;P )

Comment: Google "logic probe circuit" then click on images... There are lots of examples and methods. Though this one is probably closest to your needs.. http://www.learningelectronics.net/images/quiz/01275x01.png

Comment: If you can't disturb the line in any way then you have broken that rule straight away by hanging LEDs on them. This make your question very dubious. Use a high impedance buffer and a windown comparator to determine the mid-ground between valid logic levels.

Comment: Why dubious? It just means that the monitor should behave like it only reads the bus, not (over)writes any signals to it. Like a high-impedance input. Which of course my first approach didn't do, and that's why I'm asking for a better solution.

Comment: its Heisenberg's Uncertainty principal, "You can not measure something without disturbing it". The question is, how much disturbance can you afford without breaking the integrity and functionality of the circuitry.

Comment: I already explained it. And I thought it would be obvious for anyone doing electronics what kind of "non-disturbance" I meant. Please, don't be that guy.

Comment: "I rather want to monitor all of them at once." - How do you propose to accomplish that then? Sum, XOR, OR, etc. a bunch of lines? Regardless of which function you choose to aggregate the status of the bus, you can't run away from having to individually probe each line.

Comment: Monitoring each one on its own. Just displaying all the signals at once. Wasn't it *blatantly obvious*? :| I swear, one hour later and you ask me to define alphabet and the English language if this trend maintains ;o That's why I hate StackExchange these days. Seems like nitpicking and bickering about obvious unimportant details is more on-topic here than actual stuff.

Comment: Mind the attitude! Remember, you're asking a bunch of volunteers for help here, and you're not going to get it if you alienate everyone. Those details might seem unimportant to you, but to someone who knows how this works, they're completely relevant. We can't read your mind!

Comment: @SciTwi The ULN2803's input current is gnarly. I suppose if you have one, you could try it and see what happens. (I think it would be a problem, but I can't say for sure.) Are you able to figure out how to apply it on your own and see what happens?

Comment: Yeah, quantum physics is totally relevant to a simple question about monitoring logic signals. Sure... -_-  As for the "attitude", I'm simply sick and tired of useless nitpicking I observe on SE like ALL THE TIME in EVERY question (not only mine). SE used to be a site with great and helpful community once, but it became nazi's playground recently. I'm not loving it, and I'm not gonna hide it. If anyone, this will only alienate those who don't want to help anyway, which is fine.

Comment: @SciTwi The best way to deal with trolls or nitpiki-ness is to ignore it. The reason why SE is the 'way it is' is because most channels have become more specialized, people want you to speak their language. Maybe you could clarify your definition of disturbance in terms of current, voltage or impedance. Requirements are always good in project definitions. Thanks (also remember that people are taking time to answer your questions)

Comment: @SciTwi  I hope you understand where you went wrong and why mine works depending on Vcc and desire for Dim LEDs or Off in tri-state. Because you have gone silent since.....Pls make the effort as we have.  The Blue /Green LEDs will behave tristate and not load your bus significantly (2mA) yet be bright if using cheap 5~10Cd LEDs . I have tons of them.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how lightly you need to load the line to think that you're not disturbing it.

Something like an LM393 dual comparator would suit my requirements if I was making a logic probe. An input current of 25nA should be low enough for anybody. The output is plenty to drive a LED, and they'll run at 5v quite happily. Cheap, and not too thirsty for supply current. What's not to love?

Set the thresholds with resistors, and use one comparator to light the red LED, the other to light the green. With slightly more complexity, you could use a switch to change the threshold levels, so you can choose 0.8v/2v thresholds for TTL, or 30%/70% levels for CMOS.

Comment: By "not disturbing" I meant not asserting any signals on the bus / not overriding anything which is there. Just reading it as a high-impedance input. The solution with comparators sounds interesting, though it would take quite a lot of chips if I wanted to monitor, let's say, 16 lines at once :q Maybe the same could be achieved with transistors somehow? (They're cheaper and take less space on a breadboard.)

Comment: @SciTwi It's unlikely that anything discrete would be anywhere near as light a load on the bus and at the same time smaller in breadboard area. On the other hand, transistors are dirt cheap (I get them 2 for a penny, or less) and they are slightly less *boutique* than using the LM393. How much loading on the bus can you really tolerate? Do you know? What's driving the bus?

Comment: The bus is driven mostly by a 85C91 microcontroller, so according to the specs it can drive up to 8 low-power Schottky inputs. So I guess as long as my monitor would only *read* from the bus, behaving like a high-impedance input, it would be OK. What I *don't* want is what my naïve first-approach circuit is doing right now: overriding the signals on the bus with 1s.

Comment: @SciTwi Got it. I'll provide an answer. Are you willing to dedicate two BJTs to each line?

Comment: Yup. Sounds OK. I also have an ULN2803 kicking around. Maybe it can be used somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my "passive" logic probe solution for you for signals < 10MHz when run at full speed. At higher speeds layout and your bus load needs to be considered.

Ignore the 5V gates just for demo purposes in my [**Simulation on Falstad.**](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%202%200.000005%2058.6985430941709%2050%205%2050%0AR%2096%20160%2056%20160%201%202%20200%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0A154%20256%20160%20384%20160%200%202%200%205%0A154%20256%20232%20384%20232%200%202%200%205%0A154%20256%20304%20384%20304%200%202%200%205%0Aw%20192%20320%20256%20320%200%0Aw%20256%20248%20256%20288%200%0Aw%20256%20104%20256%20144%200%0Aw%20256%20104%20384%20104%200%0AM%20384%20104%20384%2080%200%202.5%0AM%20384%20160%20384%20144%200%202.5%0AM%20384%20232%20384%20216%200%202.5%0AM%20384%20304%20392%20280%200%202.5%0A164%2096%20160%20176%20160%200%204%205%205%205%205%20true%0Aw%20192%20104%20192%20160%202%0Aw%20192%20192%20256%20192%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20256%20176%200%0Aw%20256%20192%20256%20216%200%0Aw%20192%20256%20192%20320%200%0Aw%20192%20224%20216%20224%200%0Aw%20216%20224%20216%20248%200%0Aw%20216%20248%20256%20248%200%0AR%2096%20256%2056%20256%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0A162%20480%20104%20528%20104%201%202.1024259%201%201%200%200.005%0A162%20528%2080%20480%2080%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.005%0Ar%20528%2080%20576%2080%200%201000%0Ar%20528%20104%20576%20104%200%201000%0AR%20576%2080%20600%2080%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20480%2080%20480%20104%200%0Aw%20480%20104%20384%20104%200%0Ag%20576%20104%20600%20104%200%0As%20192%20104%20256%20104%200%200%20false%0Ax%20203%2076%20343%2079%204%2024%20press%5Csswitch%0Ag%20576%20160%20600%20160%200%0Aw%20480%20160%20384%20160%200%0Aw%20480%20136%20480%20160%200%0AR%20576%20136%20600%20136%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20528%20160%20576%20160%200%201000%0Ar%20528%20136%20576%20136%200%201000%0A162%20528%20136%20480%20136%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.003%0A162%20480%20160%20528%20160%201%202.1024259%201%201%200%200.003%0A162%20480%20232%20528%20232%201%202.1024259%201%201%200%200.003%0A162%20528%20208%20480%20208%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.003%0Ar%20528%20208%20576%20208%200%201000%0Ar%20528%20232%20576%20232%200%201000%0AR%20576%20208%20600%20208%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20480%20208%20480%20232%200%0Aw%20480%20232%20384%20232%200%0Ag%20576%20232%20600%20232%200%0Ag%20576%20304%20600%20304%200%0Aw%20480%20304%20384%20304%200%0Aw%20480%20280%20480%20304%200%0AR%20576%20280%20600%20280%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ar%20528%20304%20576%20304%200%201000%0Ar%20528%20280%20576%20280%200%201000%0A162%20528%20280%20480%20280%201%202.1024259%201%200%200%200.003%0A162%20480%20304%20528%20304%201%202.1024259%201%201%200%200.003%0Ax%20481%2021%20576%2024%204%2012%202V%5CsR/Y%5CsLED%5Cs3mA%0Ax%20457%2043%20623%2046%204%2012%20500%5CsOhm%5Csload%5CsV/2%5Cson%5Cstristate%0Ax%20-10%2011%2084%2014%204%208%20T.%5CsStewart%5CsEE%5Cssince%5Cs1975%0Ax%20187%20360%20560%20363%204%2012%20Use%5CsBlue%5CsGreen%5Cs(HB%5Cstype%5Cs(3V)%5Cs%5Csfor%5CsBoth%5CsOff%5Cswhen%5Cstristate%5Cswith%5Cs5V%0Ax%20187%20382%20602%20385%204%2012%20Use%5CsBlue%5CsGreen%5Cs%5Csfor%5Cslower%5CsCapacitance%5Cs2~5pF%5Cseach%5Csvs%5CsRed%5CsYellow%5Cs25~50pF%0Ao%208%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%201%0Ao%209%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%201%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%201%0Ao%2011%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%201%0A)

[image]

WHen using tri-state CMOS the bus capacitance may limit rise time and generally 74HCLVC gates are 4.5pF each MAX @3.3V  Red/Yellow are 1.8~2V at low currents like <3mA so for 5V logic 1k works fine with HighBright (HB) 3mm or 5mm LEDs 3mm are lower capacitance than 5mm Red/Yellow are higher capacitance with 50pF at 0V and perhaps 25pF at -5V which is the Abs Max reverse V.  Blue Red are lower Capacitance 3 ~10pF each like a CMOS gate.

So the effect is with Red-Yellow in my design 500 Ohm equivalent load @2.5V 50pF in tr-state and draws 3.3mA which is plenty bright for >1000 mcd LEDs  @ 20mA so brightness is reduced by current ratio.  Full toggle speed 01010 would drive both at half brightness which ought to be brighter than tristate for Red Yellow or use Blue Green  for Off in tri-state.

If using Blue/Green on 3.3Vcc then expect Vf<=3V for LEDs and thus 0.3V/3mA = 100 Ohms your bus will float at at Vcc/2 and look like it is terminated with 100 Ohms in series with 10 pF for each LED turning On while the other looks like 100 Ohms turning off.  This will not affect IO for read writes depending on layout and signal integrity of your bus.

Comment: The pair of LEDs on the uppermost line is exactly my first naïve approach which didn't work well because if Q3 is two-directional (it can either assert signals on the bus or read signals from the bus while being in high-impedance mode), there will be current from +5V through the 1k resistor and the red LED into the Q3, which will be interpreted by the IC as logic high. And this is unwanted. The XOR gates would solve this problem, but then it will no longer be possible to check if the IC pins are floating, because the XOR output is either 0 or 1, never floating.

Comment: No that's not true. The reverse parallel equivalent circuit for Red/yellow with 1k each is >500 Ohms to 2.5V ( actually around 550 Ohms , Then for Blue green it is less than xxx uA with 2.5V on a 3V LED. Reading in 2.5V is an invalid state regardless if 10M or 1K or 100 ohms

Comment: try again... here I changed one set to Green Blue and added another switch. Wave mouse pointer and see current right of scope traces.  121 uA http://tinyurl.com/kv6vghm for "tri-State"  R/Y LEDs  were 858 uA (depends on LED somewhat) When reading your remote memory or driver needs to be < 100 Ohms, and  CMOS now is typ 50 Ohms for 5V and 25 Ohms for 3V 74ALVCxx

Answer (score 0):

This is a comparator circuit, the input impedance will be very high depending on the op amp or comparator you select (I've selected a TL081 but this is a poor choice). You can search for an op amp with a high input impedance or low IIB (bias current) on a manufacturer or distributor website for opamps.

Something like this might work, your going to have to have feedback if you want the fully off condition. I don't know what your input signal is (this is why its good to fully disclose your design). Use a large pullup to 2.5V so if the input isn't connected, no current flows through the LED's.

This is just an idea, I don't know if it will work for your application.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzr4j0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>